# MongoDB : How to loop on a field in order to lookup each value?

Tags: mongodb, loops, aggregate, lookup

I need to loop on products field in order to lookup on products collection and check product category. If category is equal some value, i m adding a new Field on my current document.

Here a sample of my first document :

```
{
   _id:(objId),
  'products':[
    {productId:987678},
    {productId:3456765}
}
```

And my products documents :

```
{_id:(objId), category:1, name:2}
```

If category is correct, i use addField to add this on my first document:

```
category:true;
```

I can't figure out how to do this. Anyone can help me, please ?

Comment: This is the stage to start with: [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/_KeECXkJTfB , here we have unwinded products before we do lookup then compared the category found and then we set the category true if found.

```
db.product.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "category",
      "localField": "products.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "inventory_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$inventory_docs",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "products.category": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            "$gt": [
              {
                $strLenCP: {
                  "$toString": {
                    "$ifNull": [
                      "$inventory_docs.category",
                      ""
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          then: true,
          else: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```